# select all non-blank rows and cells using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I've been trying to figure out how to open an input file and copy those contents to a hidden sheet on my workbook, I saw an example on how to do this but the number of rows and columns is static, and I have to use 3 different input files one of them that changes constantly so, although I've been trying to use my intuition on how to do this, I can't seem to find out the answer.

Here's it is:

```
Sub s()
' Get customer workbook...
Dim customerBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

' make weak assumption that active workbook is the target
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get the customer workbook
filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)

' copy data from customer to target workbook
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = sourceSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = sourceSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

targetSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
' Close customer workbook
customerWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

I'm using EXCEL 2007

I apologize in advance if this is an stupid noob question, but I honestly give up don't know what else to do to make it work.

The problem Is I don't know how to make it select first to last row and first to last cell (non blank both: cells and rows)

Tried this:

```
targetSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).End(xlUp).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).End(xlUp).Value 
    and this targetSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).End(xlRight).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).End(xlRight).Value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
SourceSheet.UsedRange.Copy TargetSheet.Range("A1")
```

Comment: Such an easy answer, I feel a bit like an idiot. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Don't sweat it - Everything is easy once you know it exists. :) Just glad it worked!!!